# Не работает кнопка "далее" в слайдере, в блоке контента

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Не могу разобраться как сделать рабочей в слайдере кнопку далее, чтобы она при этом находилась в блоке с контентом.

Что хочется сделать:

В блок:

```
<div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">one</div>
```

после текста one добавить

```
<button id="next" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
```

т.е. в результате, так:

```
<div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">
   one<br>
   <button id="next" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0n0ff/mjjec7oe/

Comment: тогда придется тулить кнопки в каждый слайд, смысл?

Comment: просто нужны кнопки с разными названиями и стилями, а функционал при этом тот же - далее и назад. Ну и плюс так же сами кнопки нужны внутри контента.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Работает, если присвоить каждой кнопке `next` свой `id` и прописать его в js

```js
$(function() {
  var $cur = $('#group .cur');
  var $items = $('#group .item');

  function hideButtons() {
    $cur = $('#group .cur');
    var index = $cur.index();
    if (index > 0) {
      $('#prev').show();
    } else {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }

    if (index < $items.length - 1) {} else {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }

    if (index < $items.length - 1) {
      $('#next').show();
    } else {
      $('#next').hide();
    }
  }

  hideButtons();
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $cur.next().addClass('cur');
    $cur.removeClass('cur');
    hideButtons();
  });
  $('#nextt').click(function() {
    $cur.next().addClass('cur');
    $cur.removeClass('cur');
    hideButtons();
  });
  $('#nexttt').click(function() {
    $cur.next().addClass('cur');
    $cur.removeClass('cur');
    hideButtons();
  });
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    $cur.prev().addClass('cur');
    $cur.removeClass('cur');
    hideButtons();
  });

});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}
.item.cur {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">
  <div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">one
    <button id="next" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="item js-fade fade-in">two
    <button id="nextt" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="item js-fade fade-in">three
    <button id="nexttt" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="item js-fade fade-in">four</div>
  <div id="five" class="item js-fade fade-in">five</div>
</div>
<button style="display:none" id="prev" class="js-btn btn">prev</button>
```